# valid_referers restricting host domain from accessing resources?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following nginx reverse proxy config for nodejs. I am trying to throw a 403 error every time any domain other than the host domain tries to access files with certain extentions directly from the url using the `valid_referers` directive.

This partially works and i do get a 403 error when i try to access the restricted files however it's breaking my host domain to where it's unable to access it's own resources. The browser console shows a 404 error.

Commenting out the entire `location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|js|xml|html|css)$` block makes the site function normally again. I tried adding an `Origin` header to see if that would fix it but no luck so far.

Any ideas as to what might be wrong here?

```
server {
                server_name www.foo.xyz foo.xyz;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;         
}
                location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|js|xml|html|css)$ {
                        valid_referers www.foo.xyz foo.xyz;
                        if ($invalid_referer){
                               return 403;
                      }               
              }
```

Comment: You need to duplicate all of the `proxy_` statements into the other `location` block.